# How to show ordered items in order confirmation email template in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4, magento2.4.3

I want show customer order details (product name, sku, quantity, price) as a table in order confirmation email template. How can i show those details in the email template.

Thanks.

Comment: In default magento order email template already shows name, sku, qty and subtotal in table format. do you need to add an extra column for the unit price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this in your email template

```
 {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order_id=$order_id area="frontend"}}
```

Comment: Hi @Arun Sharma , thanks for your answer its working fine. But how can i achive this other custom emails